# Issues with OkHttpClient and Lichess API (on Android)

Tags: java, android, okhttp, lichess

I’m *very* new to Android development. As a learning project, I tried adapting [this simple script for accessing the Lichess API in Java](https://github.com/tors42/lichess-oauth-pkce-app/blob/main/LichessPKCE.java) to Android. Most people seemed to agree that for Android, it would probably be better to use OkHttpClient instead of the HttpClient used in the original script. So I asked ChatGPT (yes, sorry) to help me rewrite the method `readEmail` to use OkHttpClient, and it came up with this:

```java
static String readEmail(String access_token) throws Exception {

    // Get that e-mail
    Request emailRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(lichessUri + "/api/account/email")
            .header("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .build();

    try (Response response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(emailRequest).execute()) {
        int statusCode = response.code();
        String body = response.body().string();
        String email = parseField("email", body);
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            System.out.println("/api/account/email - " + statusCode);
        }
        return email;
    }
}
```

To test this function out in the simplest way possible, I decided not to use the `login` method, but to generate an access token in the Lichess settings directly (and only giving it access to my email address).

However, I got the following error message:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\sorst\AndroidStudioProjects\TestPhoneApp10\app\src\main\java\com\example\testphoneapp10\MainActivity.java:71: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        String email = readEmail(access_token);
                                ^
1 error
```

Here is the full code (it was based on a example “Hello World” app generated by Android Studio):

```java
package com.example.testphoneapp10;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.testphoneapp10.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import okhttp3.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String lichessUri = "https://lichess.org";

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAnchorView(R.id.fab)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        String access_token = "<my access token (I'd rather not share this here)>";

        String email = readEmail(access_token);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    static String readEmail(String access_token) throws Exception {

        // Get that e-mail
        Request emailRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .url(lichessUri + "/api/account/email")
                .header("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .build();

        try (Response response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(emailRequest).execute()) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            String body = response.body().string();
            String email = parseField("email", body);
            if (statusCode != 200) {
                System.out.println("/api/account/email - " + statusCode);
            }
            return email;
        }
    }

    // Light-weight fragile "json" ""parser""...
    static String parseField(String field, String body) {
        try {
            int start = body.indexOf(field) + field.length() + 3;
            int stop = body.indexOf("\"", start);
            return body.substring(start, stop);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the file build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.testphoneapp10"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.testphoneapp10"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.6")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
}
```

In case it helps, here is the entire code that ChatGPT generated when I asked it to adapt the script to Android and use OkHttpClient. Any comments on what it does wrong here and how this could be improved will also be greatly appreciated:

```java
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class LichessPKCE {

    public static String lichessUri = "https://lichess.org";

    /**
     * This demo application will launch a Web Browser,
     * where authentication with Lichess can be made,
     * for authorization of this demo application to
     * request the e-mail address of the authenticating
     * Lichess user - and if granted - the e-mail address
     * will be fetched and printed on standard output.
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        // Perform the OAuth2 PKCE flow
        var access_token = login();

        // Fetch the e-mail address
        var email = readEmail(access_token);

        System.out.println("e-mail: " + email);

        // Logout
        logout(access_token);

    }

    static String login() throws Exception {

        // Prepare a new login.
        // We will generate a lot of parameters which will be used in this login,
        // and then the parameters are thrown away, not to be re-used.
        // I.e, next login request will have new parameters generated.

        // Setup a local bind address which we will use in redirect_uri
        var local = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 0);
        var httpServer = HttpServer.create(local, 0);
        var redirectHost = local.getAddress().getHostAddress();
        var redirectPort = httpServer.getAddress().getPort();

        var code_verifier = generateRandomCodeVerifier();

        var code_challenge_method = "S256";
        var code_challenge = generateCodeChallenge(code_verifier);
        var response_type = "code";
        var client_id = "apptest";
        var redirect_uri = "http://" + redirectHost + ":" + redirectPort + "/";
        var scope = "email:read";
        var state = generateRandomState();

        var parameters = Map.of(
                "code_challenge_method", code_challenge_method,
                "code_challenge", code_challenge,
                "response_type", response_type,
                "client_id", client_id,
                "redirect_uri", redirect_uri,
                "scope", scope,
                "state", state
                );

        var paramString = parameters.entrySet().stream()
            .map(kv -> kv.getKey() + "=" + kv.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

        // Front Channel URL, all these parameters are non-sensitive.
        // The actual authentication between User and Lichess happens outside of this demo application,
        // i.e in the browser over HTTPS.
        var frontChannelUrl = URI.create(lichessUri + "/oauth" + "?" + paramString);

        // Prepare for handling the upcoming redirect,
        // after User has authenticated with Lichess,
        // and granted this demo application permission
        // to fetch the e-mail address.
        // The random code_verifier we generated for this single login,
        // will be sent to Lichess on a "Back Channel" so they can verify that
        // the Front Channel request really came from us.
        var cf = registerRedirectHandler(httpServer, parameters, code_verifier);

        // Now we let the User authorize with Lichess,
        // using their browser
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            var desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                desktop.browse(frontChannelUrl);
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s%n%n%s%n  %s%n%n",
                        "Doh, Desktop.Action.BROWSE not supported...",
                        "Could you manually go to the following URL :) ?",
                        frontChannelUrl);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.format("%s%n%n%s%n  %s%n%n",
                    "Doh, Desktop not supported...",
                    "Could you manually go to the following URL :) ?",
                    frontChannelUrl);
        }

        // Blocking until user has authorized,
        // and we've exchanged the incoming authorization code for an access token
        var access_token = cf.get();

        httpServer.stop(0);

        return access_token;
    }

    static String readEmail(String access_token) throws Exception {

        // Get that e-mail
        var emailRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(lichessUri + "/api/account/email"))
            .GET()
            .header("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .build();

        var response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(emailRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        var statusCode = response.statusCode();
        var body = response.body();
        var email = parseField("email", body);
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            System.out.println("/api/account/email - " + statusCode);
        }
        return email;

    }

    static void logout(String access_token) throws Exception {
        var logoutRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(lichessUri + "/api/token"))
            .DELETE()
            .header("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
            .build();

        var response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(logoutRequest, BodyHandlers.discarding());
        var statusCode = response.statusCode();
        if (statusCode != 204) {
            System.out.println("/api/token - " + response.statusCode());
        }
    }

    static String generateRandomCodeVerifier() {
        var bytes = new byte[32];
        new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
        var code_verifier = encodeToString(bytes);
        return code_verifier;
    }

    static String generateCodeChallenge(String code_verifier) {
        var asciiBytes = code_verifier.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        MessageDigest md;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa_ehhh) {
            throw new RuntimeException(nsa_ehhh);
        }

        var s256bytes = md.digest(asciiBytes);

        var code_challenge = encodeToString(s256bytes);
        return code_challenge;
    }

    static String generateRandomState() {
        var bytes = new byte[16];
        new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
        // Not sure how long the parameter "should" be,
        // going for 8 characters here...
        return encodeToString(bytes).substring(0,8);
    }

    static String encodeToString(byte[] bytes) {
         return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
            .replaceAll(  "=",  "")
            .replaceAll("\\+", "-")
            .replaceAll("\\/", "_");
    }

    static CompletableFuture<String> registerRedirectHandler(HttpServer httpServer, Map<String, String> requestParams, String code_verifier) {
        var cf = new CompletableFuture<String>();
        httpServer.createContext("/",
                (exchange) -> {
                    httpServer.removeContext("/");

                    // The redirect arrives...
                    var query = exchange
                        .getRequestURI()
                        .getQuery();

                    var inparams = Arrays.stream(query.split("&"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    s -> s.split("=")[0],
                                    s -> s.split("=")[1]
                                    ));

                    var code = inparams.get("code");
                    var state = inparams.get("state");

                    if (! state.equals(requestParams.get("state"))) {
                        cf.completeExceptionally(new Exception("The \"state\" parameter we sent and the one we recieved didn't match!"));
                        return;
                    }

                    if (code == null) {
                        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(503, -1);
                        cf.completeExceptionally(new Exception("Authorization Failed"));
                        return;
                    }

                    // We have received meta data from Lichess,
                    // about the fact that the User has authorized us - yay!

                    // Let's respond with a nice HTML page in celebration.
                    var responseBytes = "<html><body><h1>Success, you may close this page</h1></body></html>".getBytes();
                    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, responseBytes.length);
                    exchange.getResponseBody().write(responseBytes);


                    // Now,
                    // let's go to Lichess and ask for a token - using the meta data we've received
                    var tokenParameters = Map.of(
                            "code_verifier", code_verifier,
                            "grant_type", "authorization_code",
                            "code", code,
                            "redirect_uri", requestParams.get("redirect_uri"),
                            "client_id", requestParams.get("client_id")
                            );

                    var tokenParamsString = tokenParameters.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(kv -> kv.getKey() + "=" + kv.getValue())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

                    var tokenRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(lichessUri + "/api/token"))
                        .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(tokenParamsString))
                        .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .build();

                    try {
                        var response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(tokenRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
                        var statusCode = response.statusCode();
                        var body = response.body();

                        if (statusCode != 200) {
                            System.out.println("/api/token - " + statusCode);
                        }
                        var access_token = parseField("access_token", body);

                        if (access_token == null) {
                            System.out.println("Body: " + body);
                            cf.completeExceptionally(new Exception("Authorization Failed"));
                            return;
                        }

                        // Ok, we have successfully retrieved a token which we can use
                        // to fetch the e-mail address
                        cf.complete(access_token);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        });
        httpServer.start();
        return cf;
    }

    // Light-weight fragile "json" ""parser""...
    static String parseField(String field, String body) {
        try {
            int start = body.indexOf(field) + field.length() + 3;
            int stop = body.indexOf("\"", start);
            var field_value = body.substring(start, stop);
            return field_value;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You better get started using okhttp with and url where you dont have to authenticate. Keep it simple.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks, but I don’t know any such URLs to test it with. Suggestions are more than welcome. Anyway, since I already have an explicit access token, isn’t it almost as simple?

Comment: You can visit any webpage. Determine the url of a picture of it. Try to download that picture. The internet is open. You can download anything.